Counting Permutations of Boss Fights with Divisibility and Round Constraints in an RPG Game
I am working on a combinatorics problem related to an RPG game and would appreciate some help.
In this RPG, you have a team of 4 players, and you can fight $N$ different bosses. Each boss $i$ has a payout $b_i$ (an integer), which represents the amount of gold you receive for defeating that boss.
Your task is to fight a minimum of $L$ rounds and a maximum of $U$ rounds. You can choose to fight the same boss multiple times, and the order in which you fight the bosses matters (i.e., permutations are considered).
The goal is to determine the number of different valid permutations of boss fights such that the total amount of gold obtained is divisible by 4 (so that each teammate can receive an equal share).
How can I approach this problem? Any guidance or methods to count these permutations would be greatly appreciated.
What is the number of valid permutations of boss fights under these conditions?
Constraints:

$N$ is the number of bosses.
$L$ is the minimum number of rounds.
$U$ is the maximum number of rounds.
$b_i$ is the payout for boss $i$, where $b_i \in \mathbb{Z}$.
The sum of gold from any valid sequence of boss fights must be divisible by 4.

Any help with how to structure the solution or the relevant combinatorial methods would be appreciated!
I've only come up with this equation so far: (where $a_i$ is how many times you defeated boss $i$)
$$a_1 \cdot b_1 + a_2 \cdot b_2 + \dots + a_N \cdot b_N \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$$
And I've thought about using stars and bars on $ L \leq a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_N \leq U $
But I'm not sure where to go from there.

First, if permutations matter, then I would suggest not defining the $a_i$ at all, but simply to consider all $r$-tuples $(k_1,\dots,k_r)$ (let's fix a choice of $L\le r\le U$ for now—we can always sum over $r$ later), where each $k_i \in \{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ represents which boss was defeated that round. The number of such $r$-tuples is of course $N^r$, and the payout from any given $r$-tuple is $\sum_{j=1}^r b_{k_j}$. Note that we might expect roughly $\frac14N^r$ of the permutations to be valid (unless there's something special like all the $b_k$ being multiples of $4$ already).
One sneaky way of detecting whether an integer $M$ is a multiple of $4$ is to use
$$
\frac14\sum_{a=0}^3 i^{aM} = \frac{1^M + i^M + (-1)^M + (-i)^M}4 = \begin{cases} 1, &\text{if $M$ is a multiple of $4$}, \\ 0, &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
(where $i=\sqrt{-1}$). Therefore the number of valid $r$-tuples is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k_1=1}^N \cdots \sum_{k_r=1}^N \biggl( & \frac14 \sum_{a=0}^3 i^{a\sum_{j=1}^r b_{k_j}} \biggr) = \sum_{k_1=1}^N \cdots \sum_{k_r=1}^N \biggl( \frac14 \sum_{a=0}^3 \prod_{j=1}^r (i^{a})^{b_{k_j}} \biggr) \\
&= \frac14 \sum_{a=0}^3 \prod_{j=1}^r \sum_{k_j=1}^N (i^{a})^{b_{k_j}} \\
&= \frac14 \sum_{a=0}^3 \biggl( \sum_{k=1}^N (i^{a})^{b_k} \biggr)^r \\
&= \frac14 \biggl( \biggl( \sum_{k=1}^N 1^{b_k} \biggr)^r + \biggl( \sum_{k=1}^N i^{b_k} \biggr)^r + \biggl( \sum_{k=1}^N (-1)^{b_k} \biggr)^r + \biggl( \sum_{k=1}^N (-i)^{b_k} \biggr)^r \biggr).
\end{align*}
(The second equals sign is the mind-blowing one if you haven't seen something like this before; it's a vast generalization of the FOIL-like factorization $\sum_{k_1=1}^2 \sum_{k_2=1}^2 \prod_{j=1}^2 x_{j,k_j} = \prod_{j=1}^2 \sum_{k_j=1}^2 x_{j,k_j}$, which is just annoying notation for $ay+az+by+bz=(a+b)(y+z)$.)
This last expression is something that can be computed without much problem for any given $r$, knowing the $b_k$.
Notice that the first sum on the right-hand side is $N^r$, and so if the last three sums are small then we really do get something near $\frac14 N^r$ as we expected.
Of course the question only depends on the value of each $b_k$ modulo $4$ to begin with. If we let $X_\ell$ denote the number of $b_1,\dots,b_N$ that are congruent to $\ell$ modulo $4$, then the right-hand side becomes the slightly less scary
\begin{align*}
\frac14 & \biggl( \biggl( \sum_{k=1}^N 1^{b_k} \biggr)^r + \biggl( \sum_{k=1}^N i^{b_k} \biggr)^r + \biggl( \sum_{k=1}^N (-1)^{b_k} \biggr)^r + \biggl( \sum_{k=1}^N (-i)^{b_k} \biggr)^r \biggr) \\
&= \frac14\bigl( N^r + (X_0 + iX_1 - X_2 - iX_3)^r + (X_0 - X_1 + X_2 - X_3)^r + (X_0 - iX_1 - X_2 + iX_3)^r \bigr).
\end{align*}
(And then remember to sum over $L\le r\le U$.)
